# How can I find user's facebook uid through their email?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently I have an email but I can't find the uid of that facebook . So how can I find that facebook uid via email?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: You can't, there is no official API for that. What would you need this for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to match users to an email is to authorize them with the email permission and check if it is the same one. There is no way to get or validate any user info without authorization.